# Midpoint of two n-vectors

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-trigonometry

Currently I am using n-vectors (more information can be found  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-vector)) for an accurate and singularity-free representation of coordinates on the earth's surface. For various reasons, I need to compute the midpoint of two n-vectors. How can I achieve that? I know how to do that in Cartesian R3, but not in that spherical geometry.

Comment: Convert from spherical to Cartesian coördinates?

Comment: I thought about that, but that would mean a loss of precison iirc, which I need to avoid at all costs